# ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['neato', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, graphviz

My system is win10 (x64).I have installed **Graphviz 2.44.1** under folder **E:\Program Files**, then I added **E:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin** to User variable Path and **E:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot.exe** to System variable Path. I have also used pip to install graphviz. By doing so, I can run my code in PyCharm

```
from graphviz import Digraph
import heapq as pq

graph = {
    0: [3],
    1: [0, 4],
    2: [1, 4],
    3: [1],
    4: [3],
    5: [2, 4],
}

dot = Digraph(engine="neato", comment='Direct graph example')
dot.attr(overlap="false", splines="true")

pos = {
    0: '0,1!',
    1: '1,1!',
    2: '2,1!',
    3: '0,0!',
    4: '1,0!',
    5: '2,0!',
}

for v in graph.keys():
    dot.node(str(v), pos=pos[v])

for v in graph.keys():
    for w in graph[v]:
        dot.edge(str(v), str(w))

dot
```

Output of my code:

[image: Output of my code]

But when I run it in Jupyter Notebook, there is still an error **"ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['neato', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH"**. I noticed that someone suggested to add the path manually, like this：

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'E:\\Program Files\\Graphviz 2.44.1\\bin'
```

However, it still doesn't work. I have tried to reinstall it several times, but nothing works. Really need some help.

Comment: What happens when you change `dot.attr(overlap="false", splines="true")` to `dot.attr(overlap="false"; splines="true")` (so `;` instead of `,`). Note it is better to post your output as code not as an image.

Comment: If change symbol, there will be a syntax error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Got it, I will pay attention to this next time. 

Comment: The syntax error I understand, the used syntax is OK (When testing I typed a `,` in the dot file that should not be present).

Comment: *"I added \[...\] **E:\Program Files\Graphviz 2.44.1\bin\dot.exe** to System variable Path"* - That doesn't make sense. You do not add fully qualified executable names to the `PATH` environment variable. It holds directories only. Regardless, since we cannot see your environment variables, there's little we can do to help, though it definitely looks like the issue is there. Besides, this question is likely off-topic here, too.

Comment: Got it, but I just follow the instructions to do that, and what I am most concerned about is why it can be used normally in Pycharm, but there are still problems with jupyter notebook. This is really confusing. But still thanks for your reply. 